# JavaFX set length between ticks in ScatterChart

Tags: java, javafx

Here is my problem I wanted to have the same length between every ticks in my graph, no matter the size of the graph, for example :

[Graph 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1N2zv.png)

[Graph 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZ3x2.png)

As you can see the graph is re size every time and I don't know how to set up the same length between every ticks. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. In both the images you show, there are 12 tick marks per year, so the distance between them is one month in each case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry about my english, but I found an answer and this is what I was looking for : 
[What I was looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpTtJ.png)

What I was meaning is that no matter how many years there is, the graph always had the same size, I just set the size depending on how many years I will add and it's working but thanks for reply.